# How to configure Haskell in Atom text editor?

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I am new to Haskell and want to use it along with Atom text editor, please can someone tell me the steps on how to configure haskell in atom text editor?

Comment: The [first](https://atom.io/packages/language-haskell) [three](https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell) [links](https://github.com/simonmichael/haskell-atom-setup) on Google seem like a good start. As it stands, this question is too broad - it might be better to ask about particular setups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally followed a mix of these two:

[Setting Up A Haskell Development Environment (Mac OS)](http://www.prigrammer.com/?p=332) - very recent, which is good, given the focus on Atom.

[Practical Haskell - Editor Setup with Stack](http://seanhess.github.io/2015/08/05/practical-haskell-editors.html) - useful to compare things, and crosschecking packages to install in Atom.

But that's because I wanted to setup macOS, Haskell, Stack, Atom.io, using Homebrew.
Hope that's similar enough to your usecase to be useful. :)

Comment: Setting Up A Haskell Development Environment (Mac OS) link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the IDE Haskell package](https://github.com/atom-haskell/ide-haskell#readme). It includes requirements on other packages and instructions on how to install those.